# Responsive view theme switcher

Tags: javascript, jquery, themes

I want to add a theme switcher to my site, yet I am unable to locate one. I like what is being used on [this site](https://pixelarity.com/landscape), but I cannot determine what they are using. Can anyone lead me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The closest answer to your question is to change the`CSS` file based on an event such as `$('#themeSitcher').click()`. Given the fact that you've added your style sheet file like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="oldstyle.css">
```

Inside the event handler you can change this file like this:

```
$('#themeSitcher').click(function (){
   $('link[href="oldstyle.css"]').attr('href','newstyle.css');
});
```

Note that you can/should extend this approach to using more sophisticated cases, like using multiple buttons, a drop-down list, etc.